# evisa assistance scam

Tags: passports, scams, e-visas, fraud

I did a very stupid thing by applying for an evisa on this website: www.bahrainonlinevisa.com. Not sure how it happened but I did submit to them a scan of my passport, my flight reference booking (with the details on it they can manage my booking), my hotel booking and I paid 89$ (which means they have my address too). I know...

They have not responded to my emails, phone call is directed to voicemail. Now I'm terrified that whoever it is, is going to use this going to use the info for some criminal activity.
I went to the police and they told me to wait and see if there is any suspicious activity going on with my name.

Shall I cancel the plane ticket and passport as the data has been compromised? Any advice welcome as my mind is working overtime producing terrible scenarios. thank you!

Comment: They may be scammers or they may well be legit but why would they go ahead use your data for other criminal acts apart from already scamming your money? That would go against their business if at all they are scammers. Don’t think you need to cancel your passport at this stage

Comment: Just kiss your 89$ goodbye. That’s it.